# No route matches {:controller=>"queue_videos"} even I used the path from rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, controller, routes

I am stuck. I need your help, please.
Even though I used the path verified with `rake routes`

```
user_queue_videos GET    /users/:user_id/queue_videos(.:format)          queue_videos#index
```

I got following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /videos
No route matches {:controller=>"queue_videos"}
```

link in view

```
%li= link_to "My Queue", user_queue_videos_path
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :users, only: [:new, :create] do
    resources :queue_videos
  end
```

queue_videos_controller

```
  class QueueVideosController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :require_user

    def index
      @videos = current_user.my_queued_videos
    end

  end
```

I tried to use `member routes` but it did not work, so I took away but it still does not render the index template...

**2nd try: When I put**

```
  class QueueVideosController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :require_user

    def index
      @user.id = current_user.id #current_user is defined in ApplicationController
      @videos = current_user.my_queued_videos
    end

  end
```

in view

```
  %li= link_to "My Queue", user_queue_videos_path(@user.id)
```

It gives me following error:

```
RuntimeError at /videos
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

**3rd try: Then I tried following:**
in view

```
  %li= link_to "My Queue", user_queue_videos_path(current_user.id)
```

It gives me following error:

```
NoMethodError at /users/1/queue_videos

undefined method `id=' for nil:NilClass
```

**NOTE:
in ApplicationController**

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery

    helper_method :logged_in?, :current_user

    def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end

    def logged_in?
      !!current_user
    end

    def require_user
      unless logged_in?
        flash[:error] = "You don't have permission to do this"
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to you `rake routes` output and `routes.rb` you need to pass the `user_id` because is a member of user. For example:

```
%li= link_to "My Queue", user_queue_videos_path(current_user.id)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: oh I tried that too but it also give me error as: Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Comment: that's because @user isn't defined.  You need to define that.

Comment: `@user.id` is just an example. I don't now how to get the user id in your view.

Comment: Try with: `user_queue_videos_path(current_user.id)`

Comment: hmm now I got: undefined method `id=' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Make sure your `current_user` is not Nil. Maybe you are not logged in.

Comment: OK, I restart the server logged out & logged in again. still NOMethodError :(

Comment: Make sure to remove `@user.id = current_user.id` in your controller.

Comment: Ohhh now it works! Thank you very much. But why I had to remove this line ?

Comment: Cuz `@user` instance variable is not defined... is Nil.